# Addition inside println output

Tags: java

I was going through some java puzzles and found this one

```
public class Elementary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(12345 + 5432l);
    }
}
```

Isn't it supposed to print 66666, instead it prints 17777. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Note the difference between `l` and `1`

Comment: What an awful "puzzle".  Who would write code this way?

Comment: I'm so dumb.. didn't notice that.

Comment: @duffymo somebody demonstrating why you should use `L` instead of `l`.

Comment: True, @AndyTurner.  Still awful.

Comment: @ManishNegi for clear understanding please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Elementary {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(12345 + 5432l);
}
}
```

If you look closely its character 'l' in the end (5432**l**) not '1'

This means it is 'long' type value.

If there is no suffix, and it is an integral type (e.g. 5623), it is assumed to be an int. If it is not an integral type (e.g. 3.14159), it is assumed to be a double.

There are specific suffixes for long (e.g. 39832L), float (e.g. 2.4f) and double (e.g. -7.832d). 
Other than these we need to cast the numbers.

Now in you problem if you add those two numbers (12345 + 5432) you will get (17777)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the description of the answer :-
 1. if you print `12345 +54321 = 66666`.
 2. in your case it is **12345 + 5432`l`**

= 12345 +5432(This digit is long by prefixing l)l

= 12345 (int ) +5432 (long)

= (long) 12345 +5432

= 17777

More description please find the below code

```
        int i=12345;
        long j=5432l;
        int sum =  (i + j); //compilation issue
        long sum = (i + j); // no compilation 
        int sum = (int) (i + j); //Type cast works fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

You number at the moment writed as char l.  You must write number 1. 
Do you see difference l and 1

Answer (score 0):

what I believe is that since the last one in 5432l is not a digit'1' but an alphabet 'l' therefore it is simply skipped by the compiler, and results in adding 12345 with 5432

Comment: " therefore it is simply skipped by the compiler" No, it causes it to be treated as a long literal by the compiler, meaning the first number is also widened to a `long`, `long` addition is performed, and the `PrintStream.println(long)` overload is invoked.

Comment: yeah, you are right

Answer (score 0):

I agree with upper answers. But also worth mentioning that's very common mistake and that's why it is higly appreciated to code write in this way:

```
System.out.println(12345 + 5432L);
```

L - upper case, which more intuitive shows type of the variable